# Almost all $x \in E$ belongs to a closed interval

Tags: real-analysis

In proving:

Let $E$ be a Lebesgue measurable set on $\mathbb{R}$.
Show that for almost all $x \in E$ 
we have $\lim_{h \downarrow 0} \dfrac{m(E \cap [x-h, x+h] )}{2h} = 1.$

I have reduced the problem to showing that almost all $x \in E$ belongs to a closed interval $[a, b] \subset E$.

My attempt goes as the following:

Since $E$ is measurable, there exists $F_\sigma$ set $F_S$ such that $m(E) = m(F_S)$.
It suffices to show if $x \in F_S$ belongs to a closed interval.
$F_S = \cup_i F_i$ where $F_i$ is a closed set.
$F_i = G_i^c$ for some $G_i$ open. 
$G_i$ is a countable disjoint union of $I_i$ open interval.
Hence, $F_S = \cup_i \cap_i I_i^c $.

I feel like I am almost there but I am unable to finish it.
Can I get a hint to approach this problem?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it true that for $x\in E$ then $[x-h,x+h]\subseteq E$ for some $h>0$ sufficiently small?

Comment: Alessandro, it seem to me not necesserally.

Comment: @AlessandroBlasetti No. Take $[0,1]\setminus \mathbb{Q} = E$.

Comment: Your reduction seems like an oversimplification to me. It would suffice if it worked of course but I suspect it does not work.

Comment: You can use the following. Having that $m([x-h, x+h]) = 2h$ ,and that $E\cap [x-h, x+h] \subset [x-h, x+h]$, than the limit is less or equal to 1. Next use the regularity of Lebesgue measure (I mean supremum), and it seem to me that will be enough. (maybe i'm wrong).

Comment: @Tom you are right! How fool I have been.

Comment: @kolobokish, i was thinking something similar to your argument, but I think Tom have given a clearer answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Lebesgue differentiation theorem, 
$$
\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{2h} \int_{x - h}^{x + h} f\,d\lambda = f(x)
$$
for almost every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ as long as $f$ is Lebesgue integrable. So, take $f = 1_{E}$, the indicator function on $E$.